# How to auto-format the source code block in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, indentation, formatting

When I'm using org-mode to take notes about a book, sometimes I'll copy/paste some code snippets into the note file. After pasting it, I'll

```
1. `C-c '` to call `org-edit-special`
2. `C-x h` to mark all the source code
3. `TAB` to format it
```

Is there a solution in org-mode for me that, after pasting code in `#+BEGIN_SRC...#+END_SRC`, it will automatically format the code block or I can use just one key such as `TAB` to format(indent) the whole source code block?

The default `TAB`(typed in block, not using `C-c '`) is just align all lines 2 columns after `#+BEGIN_SRC` header, if there are spaces at the beginning of the second line, it will just add more spaces, it will not indent all lines like the 3 steps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is a hard solution, but it works perfect. Actually it is just a function which simulations your operations, and use a `run-at-time` to make it be called every 10 seconds.
Cheers.

```
(defun indent-org-block-automatically ()
  (when (org-in-src-block-p)
   (org-edit-special)
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (org-edit-src-exit)))

(run-at-time 1 10 'indent-org-block-automatically)
```

Of course, you can make it called every 1 second, just change 10 to 1.

Comment: I don't need `run-at-time` actually, how can I bind the `TAB` key to do the these to replace the default `TAB` when `org-in-src-block-p`. The default `TAB` is bound to `yas-expand` but it will do things as I said in my post.

Comment: It seems like there's now an `org-indent-block` function that could be used instead of the combination of `org-edit-special` and `indent-region`.

Answer (score 0):

Start with https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/aggressive-indent-mode to get the paste behavior that you describe.

You know how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wrote to solve this problem:

```
(defun udf/my-org-tab-dwim (&optional arg)
  (interactive)
  (or (org-babel-do-key-sequence-in-edit-buffer (kbd "TAB"))
      (org-cycle arg)))

(define-key org-mode-map
  (kbd "<tab>") #'udf/my-org-tab-dwim)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which is a combination of @Leu_Grady's and @kuwze's.

(1) Put the following snippet in `.emacs`:

```lisp
(defun my-indent-org-block-automatically ()
  (interactive)
  (when (org-in-src-block-p)
   (org-edit-special)
   (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
   (org-edit-src-exit)))

(define-key org-mode-map
  (kbd "C-i") #'my-indent-org-block-automatically)
```

(2) Press `C-i` when in an Org source block to auto-indent it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more modern way of doing this:

```lisp
(defvar orig-command (lookup-key org-mode-map (kbd "TAB")))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'my/org-indent-dwim)

(defun my/org-indent-dwim ()
  (interactive)
  (when (org-in-src-block-p)
    (save-excursion
      (org-babel-goto-src-block-head)
      (org-indent-block)))
  (funcall orig-command))
```

We first grab what the `TAB` key is originally bound to in `org-mode-map`, then we rebind it to `my/org-indent-dwim`. `my/org-indent-dwim` will indent the block using built-in `org-mode` functions, so no need to call `org-edit-special`. At the end, the original function that the binding was bound to is called.