# Org mode code snippets - not appearing as expected

Tags: org-mode

I would like to add snippets of code for several languages to my org files.

The code I enter has syntax highlighting, but does use correct indetation.
One language I use is python, and [I have seen here](https://youtu.be/lsYdK0C2RvQ?t=3m15s), that what I want **is possible**. In the linked video, referring to entering code snippets with the correct syntax highlighting and so fourth, Matthew says:

> "... provided you have configured the appropriate settings...".

I am not sure what I could be missing as, for example, my python works just fine in a python buffer.

I always need to open a separate buffer to achieve this, [as mentioned here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5850/how-to-auto-format-the-source-code-block-in-org-mode). The OP in that answer pasted his code in from somewhere else, but I am writing mine on the fly. Also, I do not really wish to use the accepted answer there, which is the timed-running of a custom function

As a clear example, I enter the code here, leaving my cursor at the underscore, **_** :

```
#+begin_src python
for i in range(1:23): _
∫   √

#+end_src
```

and when I press enter, I end up at the *integral sign*, **∫**. I would of coursel ike to end up at the square root symbol (sorry for overkill on symbols!). That means 4-space indent.

My Emacs 24.5 (9.0) on Mac OSX automatically inserts the `#+begin_src` and `#+end_src` all in upper case. I have tried both out and it doesn't make a difference.

I know there are some parameters one can set in the opening line, after having written the mode, in my case `python` is there. Is there a parameter to specify something like indentation in the code snippet?

Comment: Setting `(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t)` in your init file should allow you to use the tab key to indent correctly with a single keystroke instead of pressing spacebar four times (which it sounds like is your current situation), but I have not yet found a way to get automatic/electric indentation in org source blocks.

Comment: What the guy in the video does as far as I can tell (and what I do) is use `org-edit-special` (`C-c '`) to open the source block in a buffer in the language's mode where everything should work as expected, and then use `C-c'` again to go back to your org buffer.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a better, more convenient way. That video is now more that 2 years old. There are options (variables) to set in your unit file to deal with indentation in `src` snippets, but they only seem to alter how the snippets are exported. For example: `(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 4)` - meaning 4 spaces before the `#+begin_src` in e.g. AucTex output.