# How to pretty print my emacs configuration with literate programming?

Tags: literate-programming

I have done an emacs config with literate programming and I have been searching for while now. I need a simple tool with which I can just pretty print my code in my org file.

Comment: Pretty print to what/where? Only the code or also the text?

Comment: What do you mean by "pretty print"?  That normally refers to formatting code which is currently unformatted.  Surely your init file code is *already* "pretty" wrt formatting, so I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: @dalanicolai I want to format the code, which is in an org file.

Comment: The best way to format the code, is by formatting it while writing it. You can do this by opening the code block in a 'special edit buffer'. With the cursor on the code block, press `C-c C-'` to open it in the special edit buffer, press it again to update and jump back to the src-block. [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5850/how-to-auto-format-the-source-code-block-in-org-mode) gives a few more tricks. Of course, it should not be too difficult to fully automate this if you know some lisp, but I am not aware of an existing solution yet.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to take your Org config file as input and spit out just a lisp file with just the code as output? Or are you looking to turn it into something like HTML with code blocks that you can publish somewhere? Or what?